# Galaxy Tab 2 Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, tablet, galaxy-tab

What do I need to do to get a working emulator of Galaxy Tab 2 (ICS 4.0) 10.1 in Eclipse? In the SDK manager I can see "Galaxy Tab" addon but it's for Android 2.2 (API8).

Can I create it in AVD manager with some specific resolution, screen density, etc. settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What do I need to do to get a working simulator of Galaxy Tab 2 (ICS 4.0) 10.1 in Eclipse?

First, "emulator" and "simulator" mean different things in Android. What you are referring to is the emulator.

(I ordinarily would not quibble about this, but a Googler recently got confused over the issue, so I am trying to make sure everyone uses the term "emulator")

Second, AFAIK, Samsung has not published any specific emulator image for the Tab 2, or for most of their devices.

> Can I create it in AVD manager with some specific resolution, screen density, etc. settings?

You can find the settings of interest to you and attempt to set up an AVD that matches those settings. For example, IIRC, a Tab 2 is WXGA800 with an "Abstracted LCD density" of 240.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. About density - where can I found out the number 240? The default for WXGA800 is 160. Galaxy Tab 2 has 149ppi.

Comment: @PrimožKralj: Then I would use 160 for the "Abstracted LCD density" for your emulator. The emulator only works with the standard buckets (120, 160, 240, 320, etc.).